# How to find the number of permutations with offset restriction

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial

First question. Okay I have this problem that I've been trying to figure out for a while. I'm writing a computer program I need to quickly calculate the permutations of a set with 'n' elements with a maximum offset of 'x' from their original position.

Say a have a set of four letters (A, B, C, D) and a maximum offset of 2, these would be valid:
ABCD  original set obviously valid
BACD  valid
BCAD  also valid

BCDA
would be invalid because A is in the 4th column and it can only be in the first three columns(max of 2 from original column 1)
DABC
would be invalid because of D for the same reason

What would be the formula to find the number of possible permutations and could you explain to me in laymans terms how this is so(not the best with math)? I assume it would be n! - (something to do with the number of columns an element couldn't exist in). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to generate the actual permutations (first part of OP), count them (last part), or both? The latter is not trivial, see [here](https://oeis.org/A002526) for an example and references. Depending on how large $n$ and $x$ are, it can be utterly impractical to generate them (how large might these be in your case?). The generation part might be better answered on one of the programming/code StackExchange sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, counting these is not trivial (in the sense of some simple closed-form).

In the case of your example, this is [OEIS A002524](https://oeis.org/A002524). You can take a look at the references there (and/or in the link in my comment) for the mathematical details.

The *Kløve* paper goes into great detail, the *Lehmer* paper is also detailed, but only sketches some of the proofs. There are also links to tables for the particular case of your example going up to lengths of 400, same for the related sequences at OEIS for maximum displacement of 3, 4, ... (I think OEIS has none past displacement 9).

Bottom line: You can use permanents of specifically formed matrices, generating functions, or more esoteric means outlined in the references.

The numbers grow quite quickly - here's a snippet done in *Mathematica* for lengths up to 12 with maximum allowed displacement up to length-1:

[image]

This took a few seconds to calculate using non-compiled code on a netbook, so I'd imagine the same on one of my workstations using C/Fortran would be a few hundredths of a second.

I did not investigate too deeply on efficient algorithms to generate such permutations,
but coding up a quick-and-dirty in *Mathematica* produces results for the 10 length / 5 maximum displacement case in a few seconds, again non-compiled and on a netbook, so I'd venture under a tenth of a second using a real machine and compiled code.

(This was coded as a simple recursion, taking the allowable positions for the first element, appending the complement of "taken" positions from the allowable positions for the second element... recursed to the Nth element position).

Using it against your example results in:

[image]

Update: Per your comment request, here's the *Mathematica* snippet to generate these, caveat again this is in no way researched for efficiency - it was barfed out Q&D. If you don't know *Mathematica*, might not make any sense, if so comment and I'll "unroll" it to p-code.

> With[{l = #1, d = #2}, 
>      Nest[Flatten[With[{c = #, t = Length@# + 1}, Append[c, #] & /@
>             Complement[Range[Max[t - d, 1], Min[t + d, l]], c]] & /@ #, 
>         1] &, {{}}, l]] &[4, 2]

The $[4,2]$ above are the length and max. displacement arguments, output is the mappings of element to position:

> {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,4,3},{1,3,2,4},{1,3,4,2},{1,4,2,3},{1,4,3,2},{2,1,3,4},{2,1,4,3},{2,3,1,4},{2,4,1,3},{3,1,2,4},{3,1,4,2},{3,2,1,4},{3,4,1,2}}

Update: Sketch of the generator as per comment request.

OK, a reminder again, this method was a quick&dirty - there are undoubtedly more efficient means to do this (though I doubt hugely so, since the only "excess" work done here is the occasional probe that shows an element has no available valid positions.) My gut feeling is that any more efficient means would only really benefit at sizes where generating all valid combos would become unrealistic/unusable.

So, we work on a list of evolving valid sequences of positions. We start with a list of an empty list {{}}.

Now, for each list of the top-level list of lists, we replace it with a list that contains any prior positions, appending each valid new element's position.

So, for your example, the top-level list would become {{1},{2},{3}}, since those are the only valid positions the first element of a combination can take (these are just the element position -/+ the allowed offset, clipped to stay within the range of 1 to the eventual total length.)

So, at this point, we've got all the valid positions for the first element, so we repeat the above for the second element for *each* of those lists. Let's take the {1} list. We know the second element in your example can be any position from 1 to 4 (2 -/+2, clipped). But for this list, 1 is already used earlier in the list, so the valid positions are 2,3,4. So we generate new lists replacing the {1} list with {1,2},{1,3},and {1,4}.

We do this for all of the current lists in the top-level list, getting a new top-level list of {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,1},{2,3},{2,4},{3,1},{3,2},{3,4}}.

Repeating this process until we've reached the desired total length (4) gives us the position mapping shown earlier.

You can choose to use recursion or nested iteration - whatever best fits your style and the language in use.

If that's not clear, feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the references! Was having trouble finding info regarding this. I needed the function to see which combinations of length and displacement would be reasonable to calculate, and the table answers that.  Can you post the code you used generate the permutations? That'd really get me going in the right direction with this. Again thanks.

Comment: @bacon_is_good: Added snippet per request.

Comment: Ha. Yea, please "unroll" it. Have no idea what to make of that.

Comment: @bacon_is_good: Added sketch, let me know that it makes sense.

Comment: Yea, makes sense and it looks pretty efficient to me! I was planning on using this in conjunction with a queue where each elements might have a displacement that is different from their position in the set so this will work perfectly for that.